# Ubuntu 16.04 fatal JRE error

Tags: java, intellij-idea, runtime-error, fatal-error

Since yesterday all my IntelliJ applications quit running due to a JVM fatal error.

This it the error I get everytime:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0xa7b55215, pid=23009, tid=0x7fa5db40
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_121-b13) (build 1.8.0_121-8u121-b13-0ubuntu1.16.04.2-b13)
# Java VM: OpenJDK Server VM (25.121-b13 mixed mode linux-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# J 3804 C2 com.intellij.util.lang.ClassPath$ResourceStringLoaderIterator.process(Lcom/intellij/util/lang/Loader;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (14 bytes) @ 0xa7b55215 [0xa7b54720+0xaf5]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

The entire output log is this:

```
---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x09836c00):  JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0 2016.3#PY-163.8233.8 PyCharm, eap:false, os:Linux 4.8.0-39-generic, java-version:Oracle Corporation 1.8.0_121-8u121-b13-0ubuntu1.16.04.2-b13" [_thread_in_Java, id=23042, stack(0x7fa0d000,0x7fa5e000)]

siginfo: si_signo: 11 (SIGSEGV), si_code: 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr: 0x0000000c

Registers:
EAX=0xccccccce, EBX=0x00000000, ECX=0x00000000, EDX=0x00000000
ESP=0x7fa5af20, EBP=0x00000000, ESI=0x5bad8a82, EDI=0x00000004
EIP=0xa7b55215, EFLAGS=0x00210293, CR2=0x0000000c

Top of Stack: (sp=0x7fa5af20)
0x7fa5af20:   b70c7b88 b6204ff8 7fa5af5c 010a6000
0x7fa5af30:   b6204ff8 000001e7 00000000 91205628
0x7fa5af40:   87824608 91160a80 91aca690 0000000f
0x7fa5af50:   00000002 91161a18 cc4b2ffd 0000001b
0x7fa5af60:   00000001 00000004 5bad8a93 00000012
0x7fa5af70:   00000001 878246f0 00000011 00000011
0x7fa5af80:   0a0f1638 0a0f1638 7fa5afd8 b6de4a5c
0x7fa5af90:   87824564 87824634 87824628 a7391c9e 

Instructions: (pc=0xa7b55215)
0xa7b551f5:   c9 89 5c 24 48 8b e9 c1 e5 02 85 ed 0f 8c de 3a
0xa7b55205:   00 00 3b 6c 24 5c 0f 8d 94 40 00 00 c5 f9 7e e3
0xa7b55215:   0f b7 5c 6b 0c 8b fd 47 85 ff 0f 8c 24 3b 00 00
0xa7b55225:   3b 7c 24 5c 0f 8d ea 40 00 00 c5 f9 7e e7 0f b7 

Register to memory mapping:

EAX=0xccccccce is an unknown value
EBX=0x00000000 is an unknown value
ECX=0x00000000 is an unknown value
EDX=0x00000000 is an unknown value
ESP=0x7fa5af20 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x09836c00
EBP=0x00000000 is an unknown value
ESI=0x5bad8a82 is an unknown value
EDI=0x00000004 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x7fa0d000,0x7fa5e000],  sp=0x7fa5af20,  free space=311k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
J 3804 C2 com.intellij.util.lang.ClassPath$ResourceStringLoaderIterator.process(Lcom/intellij/util/lang/Loader;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (14 bytes) @ 0xa7b55215 [0xa7b54720+0xaf5]
J 1042 C1 com.intellij.util.lang.ClasspathCache.iterateLoaders(Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/intellij/util/lang/ClasspathCache$LoaderIterator;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (240 bytes) @ 0xa74c04d0 [0xa74bf820+0xcb0]
J 1076 C1 com.intellij.util.lang.ClassPath.getResource(Ljava/lang/String;Z)Lcom/intellij/util/lang/Resource; (190 bytes) @ 0xa74dd31c [0xa74dd100+0x21c]
J 1079 C1 com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.findClass(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class; (53 bytes) @ 0xa74e11b0 [0xa74e0fe0+0x1d0]
J 271 C1 java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Ljava/lang/String;Z)Ljava/lang/Class; (122 bytes) @ 0xa72db324 [0xa72dad80+0x5a4]
J 3762 C2 java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class; (7 bytes) @ 0xa7380168 [0xa7380140+0x28]
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [libjvm.so+0x51d4cd]
V  [libjvm.so+0x744165]
V  [libjvm.so+0x51b006]
V  [libjvm.so+0x51b57b]
V  [libjvm.so+0x851563]
V  [libjvm.so+0x84ffdf]
V  [libjvm.so+0x851fe6]
V  [libjvm.so+0x7b3e2a]
V  [libjvm.so+0x7b468c]
V  [libjvm.so+0x56a991]
V  [libjvm.so+0x56aba7]  JVM_GetClassDeclaredMethods+0xa7
j  java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Z)[Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;+0
J 1754 C1 java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Z)[Ljava/lang/reflect/Method; (67 bytes) @ 0xa7671388 [0xa7671140+0x248]
j  java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;+11
j  java.awt.Component.isCoalesceEventsOverriden(Ljava/lang/Class;)Z+97
j  java.awt.Component.access$500(Ljava/lang/Class;)Z+1
j  java.awt.Component$3.run()Ljava/lang/Boolean;+4
j  java.awt.Component$3.run()Ljava/lang/Object;+1
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [libjvm.so+0x51d4cd]
V  [libjvm.so+0x744165]
V  [libjvm.so+0x51c60a]
V  [libjvm.so+0x569ba4]  JVM_DoPrivileged+0x434
C  [libjava.so+0x9d84]  Java_java_security_AccessController_doPrivileged__Ljava_security_PrivilegedAction_2+0x24
J 933  java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;)Ljava/lang/Object; (0 bytes) @ 0xa7465c75 [0xa7465be0+0x95]
j  java.awt.Component.checkCoalescing()Z+56
j  java.awt.Component.<init>()V+118
j  java.awt.Container.<init>()V+1
j  javax.swing.JComponent.<init>()V+1
j  javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(Ljava/awt/LayoutManager;Z)V+1
j  javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(Ljava/awt/LayoutManager;)V+3
j  com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionToolbarImpl.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/intellij/openapi/actionSystem/ActionGroup;ZZLcom/intellij/ide/DataManager;Lcom/intellij/openapi/actionSystem/ex/ActionManagerEx;Lcom/intellij/openapi/keymap/ex/KeymapManagerEx;Z)V+165
j  com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionToolbarImpl.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/intellij/openapi/actionSystem/ActionGroup;ZZLcom/intellij/ide/DataManager;Lcom/intellij/openapi/actionSystem/ex/ActionManagerEx;Lcom/intellij/openapi/keymap/ex/KeymapManagerEx;)V+176
j  com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.createActionToolbar(Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/intellij/openapi/actionSystem/ActionGroup;ZZ)Lcom/intellij/openapi/actionSystem/ActionToolbar;+62
j  com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.createActionToolbar(Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/intellij/openapi/actionSystem/ActionGroup;Z)Lcom/intellij/openapi/actionSystem/ActionToolbar;+46
j  com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeRootPane.c()Ljavax/swing/JComponent;+20
j  com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeRootPane.updateToolbar()V+6
j  com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeRootPane.<init>(Lcom/intellij/openapi/actionSystem/ex/ActionManagerEx;Lcom/intellij/ide/DataManager;Lcom/intellij/openapi/application/Application;Lcom/intellij/openapi/wm/IdeFrame;)V+130
j  com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFrameImpl.createRootPane(Lcom/intellij/openapi/actionSystem/ex/ActionManagerEx;Lcom/intellij/ide/DataManager;Lcom/intellij/openapi/application/Application;)Lcom/intellij/openapi/wm/impl/IdeRootPane;+8
j  com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFrameImpl.<init>(Lcom/intellij/openapi/application/ex/ApplicationInfoEx;Lcom/intellij/openapi/actionSystem/ex/ActionManagerEx;Lcom/intellij/ide/DataManager;Lcom/intellij/openapi/application/Application;)V+19
j  com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.WindowManagerImpl.showFrame()V+18
j  com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication$IdeStarter.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+148
j  com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.b()V+8
j  com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication$$Lambda$150.run()V+4
j  com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performUserActivity(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V+15
j  com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run()V+25
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [libjvm.so+0x51d4cd]
V  [libjvm.so+0x744165]
V  [libjvm.so+0x51c60a]
V  [libjvm.so+0x7b6725]
V  [libjvm.so+0x7b845e]
V  [libjvm.so+0x563c7e]  JVM_InvokeMethod+0x10e
C  [libjava.so+0xcf53]  Java_sun_reflect_NativeMethodAccessorImpl_invoke0+0x23
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+100
J 1668 C1 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (10 bytes) @ 0xa763d7c4 [0xa763d6e0+0xe4]
J 1667 C1 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (62 bytes) @ 0xa763d31c [0xa763d000+0x31c]
j  com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1$1.a(Lcom/intellij/idea/IdeaUltimateApplication;)V+35
j  com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1$1$$Lambda$57.run()V+4
j  java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch()V+47
j  java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;Ljava/lang/Object;)V+21
j  java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Ljava/awt/EventQueue;Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;Ljava/lang/Object;)V+3
j  java.awt.EventQueue$3.run()Ljava/lang/Void;+32
j  java.awt.EventQueue$3.run()Ljava/lang/Object;+1
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [libjvm.so+0x51d4cd]
V  [libjvm.so+0x744165]
V  [libjvm.so+0x51c60a]
V  [libjvm.so+0x569ba4]  JVM_DoPrivileged+0x434
C  [libjava.so+0x9db5]  Java_java_security_AccessController_doPrivileged__Ljava_security_PrivilegedAction_2Ljava_security_AccessControlContext_2+0x25
j  java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
j  java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+18
j  java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+46
j  com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+49
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(I)V+245
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(ILjava/awt/Conditional;Ljava/awt/EventFilter;)V+35
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(ILjava/awt/Conditional;Ljava/awt/Component;)V+11
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(ILjava/awt/Conditional;)V+4
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Ljava/awt/Conditional;)V+3
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run()V+9
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [libjvm.so+0x51d4cd]
V  [libjvm.so+0x744165]
V  [libjvm.so+0x51b006]
V  [libjvm.so+0x51b501]
V  [libjvm.so+0x55975a]
V  [libjvm.so+0x87f12b]
V  [libjvm.so+0x87f5fe]
V  [libjvm.so+0x73cb75]
C  [libpthread.so.0+0x6295]  start_thread+0xe5
C  [libc.so.6+0xe6eee]  clone+0x6e


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x84ff8c00 JavaThread "Keep-Alive-Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=23120, stack(0x7c40d000,0x7c45e000)]
  0x85804400 JavaThread "ApplicationImpl pooled thread 6" [_thread_blocked, id=23119, stack(0x7b95e000,0x7b9af000)]
  0x7a9f1c00 JavaThread "ApplicationImpl pooled thread 5" [_thread_blocked, id=23118, stack(0x7b9af000,0x7ba00000)]
  0x7b6d2c00 JavaThread "ApplicationImpl pooled thread 4" [_thread_blocked, id=23055, stack(0x7c45e000,0x7c4af000)]
  0x0a093800 JavaThread "ApplicationImpl pooled thread 3" [_thread_blocked, id=23054, stack(0x7c913000,0x7c964000)]
  0x8491e000 JavaThread "TimerQueue" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=23053, stack(0x7c971000,0x7c9c2000)]
  0x7fde2c00 JavaThread "ApplicationImpl pooled thread 2" [_thread_in_vm, id=23052, stack(0x7c7af000,0x7c800000)]
  0x09e20400 JavaThread "ApplicationImpl pooled thread 1" [_thread_blocked, id=23050, stack(0x7cd04000,0x7cd55000)]
  0x09c66000 JavaThread "process reaper" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=23049, stack(0x7cffa000,0x7d013000)]
  0x09c3a400 JavaThread "BaseDataReader: error stream of fsnotifier" [_thread_in_native, id=23047, stack(0x7d113000,0x7d164000)]
  0x09c39000 JavaThread "BaseDataReader: output stream of fsnotifier" [_thread_in_native, id=23046, stack(0x7d164000,0x7d1b5000)]
  0x09c3c000 JavaThread "ProcessWaitFor: fsnotifier" [_thread_blocked, id=23045, stack(0x7d1b5000,0x7d206000)]
  0x097d8400 JavaThread "Image Fetcher 1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=23043, stack(0x7e506000,0x7e557000)]
=>0x09836c00 JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0 2016.3#PY-163.8233.8 PyCharm, eap:false, os:Linux 4.8.0-39-generic, java-version:Oracle Corporation 1.8.0_121-8u121-b13-0ubuntu1.16.04.2-b13" [_thread_in_Java, id=23042, stack(0x7fa0d000,0x7fa5e000)]
  0x0971ac00 JavaThread "AWT-Shutdown" [_thread_blocked, id=23041, stack(0x7fc5e000,0x7fcaf000)]
  0x09719800 JavaThread "Periodic tasks thread" [_thread_blocked, id=23040, stack(0x7fcaf000,0x7fd00000)]
  0x0970d800 JavaThread "Timer-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=23039, stack(0x80391000,0x803e2000)]
  0x09703000 JavaThread "Image Fetcher 0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=23038, stack(0x80302000,0x80353000)]
  0x09657800 JavaThread "Netty Builtin Server 2" [_thread_in_native, id=23037, stack(0x7e045000,0x7e096000)]
  0x09656000 JavaThread "Netty Builtin Server 1" [_thread_in_native, id=23036, stack(0x7e096000,0x7e0e7000)]
  0x0959b800 JavaThread "process reaper" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=23035, stack(0x7e2e7000,0x7e300000)]
  0xb6208000 JavaThread "DestroyJavaVM" [_thread_blocked, id=23010, stack(0xb6359000,0xb63aa000)]
  0x8311e800 JavaThread "AWT-XAWT" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=23027, stack(0x82f5e000,0x82faf000)]
  0x8310a400 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=23026, stack(0x830af000,0x83100000)]
  0x85277800 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=23024, stack(0x84adb000,0x84b2c000)]
  0x85274800 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=23023, stack(0x84b2c000,0x84bad000)]
  0x85272c00 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=23022, stack(0x84bad000,0x84c2e000)]
  0x85271400 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=23021, stack(0x84c2e000,0x84caf000)]
  0x8526fc00 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=23020, stack(0x84caf000,0x84d00000)]
  0x8526e400 JavaThread "Surrogate Locker Thread (Concurrent GC)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=23019, stack(0x85312000,0x85363000)]
  0x85254000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=23018, stack(0x85363000,0x853b4000)]
  0x85251400 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=23017, stack(0x85900000,0x85951000)]

Other Threads:
  0x8524cc00 VMThread [stack: 0x85951000,0x859d2000] [id=23016]
  0x8527a400 WatcherThread [stack: 0x84a5a000,0x84adb000] [id=23025]

VM state:synchronizing (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread:  ([mutex/lock_event])
[0xb6205678] Safepoint_lock - owner thread: 0x8524cc00
[0xb62056e0] Threads_lock - owner thread: 0x8524cc00
[0xb6205b58] Heap_lock - owner thread: 0x09e20400

Heap:
 par new generation   total 39296K, used 26206K [0x86600000, 0x890a0000, 0x910a0000)
  eden space 34944K,  62% used [0x86600000, 0x87b57858, 0x88820000)
  from space 4352K, 100% used [0x88820000, 0x88c60000, 0x88c60000)
  to   space 4352K,   0% used [0x88c60000, 0x88c60000, 0x890a0000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 87424K, used 23139K [0x910a0000, 0x96600000, 0xa6600000)
 Metaspace       used 38557K, capacity 39691K, committed 39768K, reserved 40240K

Card table byte_map: [0x864ff000,0x86600000] byte_map_base: 0x860cc000

Marking Bits: (CMSBitMap*) 0xb6278780
 Bits: [0x85a53000, 0x864fe000)

Mod Union Table: (CMSBitMap*) 0xb62787e0
 Bits: [0xa6b69000, 0xa6b7e560)

Polling page: 0xb76d9000

CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=9670Kb max_used=9670Kb free=236089Kb
 bounds [0xa71c5000, 0xa7b75000, 0xb61c5000]
 total_blobs=3759 nmethods=3453 adapters=221
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 6,278 Thread 0x85274800 4205       3       sun.util.calendar.BaseCalendar$Date::<init> (32 bytes)
Event: 6,278 Thread 0x85274800 nmethod 4205 0xa78d2248 code [0xa78d2360, 0xa78d2500]
Event: 6,278 Thread 0x85274800 4215       3       java.util.Calendar::aggregateStamp (21 bytes)
Event: 6,278 Thread 0x85274800 nmethod 4215 0xa78d1f88 code [0xa78d20a0, 0xa78d21e0]
Event: 6,278 Thread 0x85274800 4210       1       java.text.DecimalFormat::getMaximumFractionDigits (5 bytes)
Event: 6,278 Thread 0x85274800 nmethod 4210 0xa78d1d88 code [0xa78d1e80, 0xa78d1f20]
Event: 6,283 Thread 0x85274800 4216       3       java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle::shouldBeInitialized (123 bytes)
Event: 6,284 Thread 0x85274800 nmethod 4216 0xa78d1588 code [0xa78d1700, 0xa78d1c5c]
Event: 6,288 Thread 0x85274800 4217       3       java.util.HashMap::entrySet (27 bytes)
Event: 6,288 Thread 0x85274800 nmethod 4217 0xa78d1048 code [0xa78d1180, 0xa78d1420]

Deoptimization events (10 events):
Event: 6,134 Thread 0x0a093800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0xa760bee4 method=org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement()Z @ 24
Event: 6,152 Thread 0x0a093800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0xa7adcec4 method=org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanAttribute(Lorg/apache/xerces/util/XMLAttributesImpl;)V @ 74
Event: 6,206 Thread 0x7fde2c00 Uncommon trap: reason=bimorphic action=maybe_recompile pc=0xa746707c method=gnu.trove.TIterator.hasNext()Z @ 1
Event: 6,206 Thread 0x7fde2c00 Uncommon trap: reason=bimorphic action=maybe_recompile pc=0xa7a99fe0 method=gnu.trove.THashIterator.next()Ljava/lang/Object; @ 9
Event: 6,206 Thread 0x7fde2c00 Uncommon trap: reason=bimorphic action=maybe_recompile pc=0xa746707c method=gnu.trove.TIterator.hasNext()Z @ 1
Event: 6,206 Thread 0x7fde2c00 Uncommon trap: reason=bimorphic action=maybe_recompile pc=0xa7a99fe0 method=gnu.trove.THashIterator.next()Ljava/lang/Object; @ 9
Event: 6,206 Thread 0x7fde2c00 Uncommon trap: reason=bimorphic action=maybe_recompile pc=0xa746707c method=gnu.trove.TIterator.hasNext()Z @ 1
Event: 6,207 Thread 0x7fde2c00 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0xa742e6f0 method=java.lang.Character.isSurrogate(C)Z @ 3
Event: 6,230 Thread 0x0a093800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0xa7b1c24c method=sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead([CII)I @ 130
Event: 6,288 Thread 0x09836c00 Uncommon trap: reason=range_check action=none pc=0xa7670884 method=sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.current()C @ 34

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 5,501 Thread 0x09836c00 Exception <a 'java/io/FileNotFoundException'> (0x87ec6c98) thrown at [/build/openjdk-8-JgCXLD/openjdk-8-8u121-b13/src/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 709]
Event: 5,506 Thread 0x09836c00 Exception <a 'java/io/FileNotFoundException'> (0x87f13190) thrown at [/build/openjdk-8-JgCXLD/openjdk-8-8u121-b13/src/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 709]
Event: 5,506 Thread 0x09836c00 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException': 130> (0x87fca5b8) thrown at [/build/openjdk-8-JgCXLD/openjdk-8-8u121-b13/src/hotspot/src/share/vm/interpreter/interpreterRuntime.cpp, line 366]
Event: 5,522 Thread 0x09836c00 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException': 131> (0x88006bf0) thrown at [/build/openjdk-8-JgCXLD/openjdk-8-8u121-b13/src/hotspot/src/share/vm/interpreter/interpreterRuntime.cpp, line 366]
Event: 5,579 Thread 0x09836c00 Exception <a 'sun/nio/fs/UnixException'> (0x88294bc0) thrown at [/build/openjdk-8-JgCXLD/openjdk-8-8u121-b13/src/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 709]
Event: 5,594 Thread 0x09836c00 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException': 163> (0x882c0170) thrown at [/build/openjdk-8-JgCXLD/openjdk-8-8u121-b13/src/hotspot/src/share/vm/interpreter/interpreterRuntime.cpp, line 366]
Event: 5,594 Thread 0x09836c00 Exception <a 'sun/nio/fs/UnixException'> (0x882c31a8) thrown at [/build/openjdk-8-JgCXLD/openjdk-8-8u121-b13/src/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 709]
Event: 6,288 Thread 0x09836c00 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException': 96> (0x877fd108) thrown at [/build/openjdk-8-JgCXLD/openjdk-8-8u121-b13/src/hotspot/src/share/vm/interpreter/interpreterRuntime.cpp, line 366]
Event: 6,288 Thread 0x09836c00 Exception <a 'sun/nio/fs/UnixException'> (0x877fdf58) thrown at [/build/openjdk-8-JgCXLD/openjdk-8-8u121-b13/src/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 709]
Event: 6,309 Thread 0x09836c00 Implicit null exception at 0xa7b55215 to 0x00000000

Events (10 events):
Event: 6,307 loading class org/intellij/plugins/relaxNG/RngDomFileDescription$RngElementDescription
Event: 6,307 loading class org/intellij/plugins/relaxNG/RngDomFileDescription$RngElementDescription done
Event: 6,307 loading class org/intellij/plugins/relaxNG/xml/dom/RngElement
Event: 6,307 loading class org/intellij/plugins/relaxNG/xml/dom/RngElement done
Event: 6,307 loading class org/intellij/plugins/relaxNG/RngDomFileDescription$RngGrammarDescription
Event: 6,307 loading class org/intellij/plugins/relaxNG/RngDomFileDescription$RngGrammarDescription done
Event: 6,307 loading class org/intellij/plugins/relaxNG/xml/dom/RngGrammar
Event: 6,307 loading class org/intellij/plugins/relaxNG/xml/dom/RngGrammar done
Event: 6,307 loading class org/intellij/plugins/relaxNG/xml/dom/RngGrammarContent
Event: 6,307 loading class org/intellij/plugins/relaxNG/xml/dom/RngGrammarContent done



VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Xbootclasspath/a:/usr/lib/pycharm/lib/boot.jar -Xms128m -Xmx512m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -ea -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd -Dsun.java2d.renderer=sun.java2d.marlin.MarlinRenderingEngine -XX:ErrorFile=/home/csc/java_error_in_PYCHARM_%p.log -XX:HeapDumpPath=/home/csc/java_error_in_PYCHARM.hprof -Didea.paths.selector=PyCharm2016.3 -Djb.vmOptionsFile=/usr/lib/pycharm/bin/pycharm.vmoptions -Didea.platform.prefix=Python 
java_command: com.intellij.idea.Main
java_class_path (initial): /usr/lib/pycharm/lib/bootstrap.jar:/usr/lib/pycharm/lib/extensions.jar:/usr/lib/pycharm/lib/util.jar:/usr/lib/pycharm/lib/jdom.jar:/usr/lib/pycharm/lib/log4j.jar:/usr/lib/pycharm/lib/trove4j.jar:/usr/lib/pycharm/lib/jna.jar
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle
PATH=/home/csc/bin:/home/csc/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/db/bin
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/pycharm/bin:
SHELL=/bin/bash
DISPLAY=:0

Signal Handlers:
SIGSEGV: [libjvm.so+0x8d4c70], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGBUS: [libjvm.so+0x8d4c70], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGFPE: [libjvm.so+0x73aa80], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGPIPE: SIG_IGN, sa_mask[0]=00000000000010000000000000000000, sa_flags=SA_RESTART
SIGXFSZ: [libjvm.so+0x73aa80], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGILL: [libjvm.so+0x73aa80], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGUSR1: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=00000000000000000000000000000000, sa_flags=none
SIGUSR2: [libjvm.so+0x73a8c0], sa_mask[0]=00000000000000000000000000000000, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGHUP: [libjvm.so+0x73b050], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGINT: [libjvm.so+0x73b050], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGTERM: [libjvm.so+0x73b050], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGQUIT: [libjvm.so+0x73b050], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
```

If I try to execute `java -config` I get errors

```
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I have reinstalled Java two times, but it does not solve the issue. 
Other help topics on this website and other forums did not help to solve it either.

Who knows what I can do?

Comment: 1- try `ulimit -c unlimited", 2- java -config giving me same output  (but i don't have problem), 3- how much ram u got?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried that first suggestion already. I have 16Gb of RAM. I concluded that the disk must have gotten corrupt during one of the many sudden fatal crashes I had last weekend. I run everything on an SSD.

Comment: Do you have any environment variables that set global VM options, like `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`?

Comment: Do you work on 32-bit Linux? Otherwise I'd switch to 64-bit JetBrains Runtime: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544879.

Comment: Did you try Oracle binary version instead of Openjdk version? You received crash during compilation in C2, there must be replay file also generated in the same place as you get hs_err file? could you check that file as well?